# Excel formula that use while to get a 1 digit number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

So I have to get in a cell a single digit number.If I get 92  I need to do 2+9=11 and after 1+1 =2 so 2 is my number.How I can do this with a single function?

Comment: What is a possibility to have 3 digit number and if yes then what would be the output?

Comment: if is abc you do a+b+c and if the sum is greater than 9 you repeat the process and all those repeats have to be in a single formula in a single cell

Comment: @ScottCraner in the exercise it says to use formula only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply:

`=1+MOD(A1-1,9)`

Regards

Comment: Wow wow thanks dude,do you mind if you tell us how you get to that

Answer (score 0):

You need to first validate the cell value by using below formula

```
=COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1))>0
```

if above is true then only use below formula to get your number

```
=left(A1,1)
=right(A1,1)
```

Store into a variable and than try to read digit if more than 2. May be this is helpful.

Comment: I can't use constants array in a validation